Should density be considered in the role of the strength of a gravitational field?
Ok, here me out. Black holes are usually formed from the compression of the mas released during the death of a supermassive star, however they have the same mass as the star (or even less). Yet when the star was alive, it had a finite acceleration due to gravity but when it turns into a black hole of the same mass, the acceleration due to gravity becomes infinite.
So does this mean that reducing the volume of a given mass, could increase the gravitational effect and would this mean we would need new formulas to accommodate the density of an object when calculating it's gravitational field strength ?

Let's assume we have an object with constant density $\rho$, mass $M$ and radius $R$.
Using Newtonian gravity (which is a good enough approximation in most scenarios) the force on another object of mass $m$ at a distance $r > R$ from the first object is
$\displaystyle F = \frac {GMm}{r^2}$
This does not depend on the density of the first object but only on its mass $M$.
The force due to gravity on a mass $m$ at the surface of the first object is
$\displaystyle F_{surface} = \frac {GMm}{R^2}$
At first sight this also does not appear to depend on the density $\rho$ of the first object either. However, note that $\rho$, $M$ and $R$ are connected by
$\displaystyle M = \frac {4 \pi} 3 R^3 \rho$
So the surface gravity of the first object does in fact depend on $\rho$; if we keep $M$ the same and increase $\rho$ then $R$ decreases and the surface gravity increases.

I am so grateful that you took out time of your busy schedule, to answer a question from this side of the universe, and I understand the reasoning behind why we could assume the mass alone is important.   If we look at the system, we see the density changes not because of mass increase but a volume reduction. Multiplying the new density by the new volume would give the old mass and that doesn't explain the increase in gravitational force, since the star had same mass or more.

@ChukwufumnanyaMolokwu If you mean the increase in surface gravity when density increases, this is because although the mass of the primary object stays the same, its radius decreases when its density increases. We are still applying Newton's law of gravity, but with a smaller distance to the centre of the primary object.

Thank you so much. I understand it now. God! I feel like an idiot! Thanks for explaining though.
